# Loading View Page In Library In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, classloader, codeigniter-2

In my codeigniter i created a library in library folder.I want to load view pages in that library.How can i do this?

This is my code:

```
$this->load->view('view_page');
```

But when iam using this code i get an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_theme_lib::$load

Filename: libraries/theme_lib.php

Line Number: 9
```

What is the problem in mycode?

In Line number 9 in library the code is :

```
$this->load->view('view_page');
```

Comment: have you load your library? example, $this->load->library('mylib');

Comment: yes i loaded the library

Comment: show the code on line 9 in your library or better yet, show all your code please.

Answer (score 7):

To do what you're trying to do you need to get an instance of CI, and use that.

e.g.

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Within your library functions you *could* then use this variable to load the view:

```
$CI->load->view('view_page');
```

I would question though why you want to call a view, in the form that you have done, within a library. I suspect that you would be better to get the view call to return data (setting the 3rd parameter 'true') and then have your library return the display data to the controller.... Your approach seems messy, but then I have no idea what your library is trying to do.....

Answer (score 2):

I have came across your question for different reason, I seem to have problem passing variables to views instead. Let me explain before I tell you answer to your problem.

Imagine you have an Emailer library to send emails rather than sorting that out in controller.
Emailer than within itself builds email string using views. My problem is that when I make my call from controller something like Emailer::send_mail($data,$template) it passes the variables correctly but when I do it from another library the view fails to register the variables. LOL

So yes Stéphane Bourzeix you do sometimes want to use output from view in a different way than just returning to client browser.

The solution is here.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html

the last section of that page has something like

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);
```

but something like

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', $view_data, true);
```

should work too

in case of doing this from other places than controllers you will need to:

```
$this->ci = & get_instance();
$string = $this->ci->load->view("myfile",$view_data,true);
```

it seems like the last argument in the list (true) is the one that tells it not to render to browser but instead just create string with template content

I know it's a bit too late but hope it still helps to some. Good luck with your code.

tomhre

Answer (score 0):

You simply DON'T load pages (aka Views) in a Library.
I don't see any need for doing this.

Comment: Exactly.  The OP should be doing this in the controller.  In the library you should be returning data to then be passed to the view for presenting.

Comment: That's not an answer though. There is no reason why you *can't* do it, which isn't the same as not seeing any reason why you personally would.

Comment: You can't do it because the CI object is not available in a Lib, as you mentioned it in your answer, you need to instanciate it before. I think i'm fairly right in saying that it is a wrong idea and that's why it is not avail in the first place ;-)

Comment: Let's say that you load all the time the same views, let's say you do that in 6 lines of code because you're loading a lot of views. Why can't you just have that in a Library? I do see the point of loading views in a Library.

Comment: You're just breaking MVC, OP and CI best practices, as mentionned before the CI object is even NOT available in a Lib

Comment: I know this is a bit old now, but one potential reason for this could creating a widget class. You could simply load the view as a variable (rather than output it) and return it to the controller. Therefore, if nothing else, keeping your code DRY and re-useable.

Comment: I do it in my custom 404 function

Comment: I do need this as well in my custom template engine.

Comment: Here is a reason: I load a view inside a library in order to print PDF files with DOMPDF. I have to use a library because I'm calling these functions inside many controllers and I can't redirect the user inside controllers. (I'm processing some background notifications)